# How to Change Timeline Division Markers to Match Chosen Frame Rate?

Tags: timeline, frame-rate

I can change the frame rate of an animation easily enough. What I can't do is reflect this change on the timeline. The timeline division markers are displayed in an interval that is different depending on the editor window's current zoom level. At first glance, it looks as if they appear in increments based on multiples of ten. But in actuality, there is a pattern: 1, 2, 5. So as you zoom out, divisions which once appeared as multiples of 10, become multiples of 20, then 50, then 100, then 200, then 500, etc. What I want is for them to always appear in multiples of the current frame rate. So, any time a new frame rate is chosen, the division markers will update to reflect what timeline divisions will look like at the newly chosen frame rate. Below is what this might look like. On the left is how it is now, and on the right, how I'd like it.

[image]

Is there a way to display the timeline division markers as multiples of the chosen frame rate instead of in multiples of arbitrary numbers?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to stop this, however, Asked [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38783/using-the-z-depth-buffer-when-drawing-from-bgl-draw-callbacks) re doing something similar back in 2.7x.  _ie_ draw your "own thing" above  space background and below timelines, cursor etc_ See also [re getting the coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38681/getting-area-region-view2d-pixel-coordinates-of-2d-views-vse-nla)